# Select Based on Prev Records

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *, to_char(time, 'Day') as weekday,
    CASE
      WHEN close > open  THEN 'Bull'
      ELSE 'Bear'
    END AS bull_bear
    FROM dukasohlc_day where symbol = 'US30' order by time asc limit 300;
```

[image]

However I would like to be able to make this query in a way so that only "Monday" records where "Thursday and Friday" where "Bear" are returned, for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at LAG window function. If you post ddl for table and insert statements for sample data it is easier to help you. You can also use a service like https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30 and post the url

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini I have added it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/kVcmPw5z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example, you need to change it so that it only considers previous week for the same year (or the year before if week is 1), but I'll post it anyhow:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, to_char(time, 'Day') as weekday
        , EXTRACT(isodow from time) as dy 
        , EXTRACT(week from time) as wk
        , LAG(extract(week from time)) OVER (ORDER BY time) as prev_wk
        , CASE WHEN close > open  THEN 'Bull'
                               ELSE 'Bear'
          END AS bull_bear
   FROM dukasohlc_day where symbol = 'US30'
) 
SELECT * 
FROM t AS t1
WHERE t1.wk = 2
  AND EXTRACT(year FROM time) = 2022
  AND t1.dy = 1
  AND EXISTS (
      -- was last friday bear?
      SELECT 1 FROM t AS t2
      WHERE t2.prev_wk = t1.wk - 1
        AND t2.dy = 5
        AND t2.bull_bear = 'Bear'
        AND EXTRACT(year FROM t2.time) = EXTRACT(year FROM t1.time)
  )
  AND EXISTS (
      -- was last thursday bear?
      SELECT 1 FROM t AS t2
      WHERE t2.prev_wk = t1.wk - 1
        AND t2.dy = 4
        AND t2.bull_bear = 'Bear'
        AND EXTRACT(year FROM t2.time) = EXTRACT(year FROM t1.time)
 )  
ORDER BY time asc limit 300;
```

If we replace EXISTS with a JOIN it is possible to inspect the day and bull_bear value:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, to_char(time, 'Day') as weekday
        , EXTRACT(isodow from time) as dy 
        , EXTRACT(week from time) as wk
        , LAG(extract(week from time)) OVER (ORDER BY time) as prev_wk
        , CASE WHEN close > open  THEN 'Bull'
                               ELSE 'Bear'
          END AS bull_bear
   FROM dukasohlc_day where symbol = 'US30'
) 
SELECT t1.*, t2.weekday, t2.bull_bear, t3.weekday, t3.bull_bear 
FROM t AS t1
JOIN t AS t2
  ON t2.prev_wk = t1.wk - 1
  AND t2.dy = 5
  AND t2.bull_bear = 'Bear'
  AND EXTRACT(year FROM t2.time) = EXTRACT(year FROM t1.time)
JOIN t AS t3
  ON t3.prev_wk = t1.wk - 1
  AND t3.dy = 4
  AND t3.bull_bear = 'Bear'
  AND EXTRACT(year FROM t3.time) = EXTRACT(year FROM t1.time)
WHERE t1.dy = 1  
ORDER BY time asc limit 300;
```

Note that this does not handle the beginning/end of the year unless this is handled by the market (closed during new year)

Comment: Hi @Lennart, thanks for the reply. I have tried your code and it seems to be buggy. If you change the year to 2023 for example, from the recordset returned you should get the Monday date 2023-01-09 01:00:00+00


However if you look at the dataset, the Previous Thursday and Friday (2023-01-05 and 2023-01-06) are "Bear" and "Bull"

Comment: You need to ensure that the year in the exists is the same as the year in the outer select. I was in a rush but wanted to give you a sketch anyhow

Comment: Thank you, I made some modifications and it seems to be working now!